# Create FAQ chatbot and manage user session

Tags: php, chatbot, whatsapp

I working on to create FAQ chatbot in PHP. I want to know that how I can build chat flow so that I can know in which question currently user is and reply based on that. Basically I want know how I can maintain session for chatbot flow for user.

I have little experience in creating chatbot. So I want to know what are the way to resolve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ChatBot**

If you want to get started really fast I would reckon you can use something like [Botman](https://botman.io/2.0/installation), this will let you get started with the chatbot bit, a bot that can take in a question and pass it to function which can then answer. Also since the project is open source you can have a look at how they manage sessions which can be helpful too.

**FAQ Smarts**

If you want to add the FAQ smarts to your chatbot, you can rely on OpenAI's completion API and use "text-davinci-003" model which can answer the questions based on the FAQs. Also, would recommend fine-tuning the model for better results.

Bear it this would be paid API but is not very expensive if users are not brute in nature and it would be very strongly recommended that the chatbot be either captcha protected or sit in an authenticated space.